# Fix Visual Studio 2013 Error List

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, error-list

This problem has been bugging me for some time now. I can build the project and the code looks correct but no matter what I do, I still get errors in the errors list (which infact stops some features working inside visual studio). I can still run the project completely fine.

[image]

And as an example here is ConnectionState, which clearly shows it being inside the namespace!

```
namespace Versioning 
{   
public enum ConnectionState     
{       Connected,      Disconnected    }
...
}
```

Side notes:

1) I have tried explicitly adding the assembly. i.e.
xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MyProject.Helpers;assembly=**MyAssembly**"

2) This is not on a shared network drive.

3) I have rebooted visual studio

Comment: Looks like XAML misery, that unholy source of trouble.  You must provide a minimum repro to get help with that.

Comment: Is it WPF/ XAML? can you your xaml file also?

Comment: I have 100s of XAMLs there are lots of errors spread across many files. Im not sure how I can show just one... hmm

Comment: the error list will show the name of the XAML file..see if you have added reference in those projects for your assembly.

Comment: Dumb question, but have you tried compiling multiple times?  Sometimes when you reference a class in XAML that exists inside the same project as the XAML you need to compile more than once.

Comment: Yeah ive compiled 100s of times :).

Comment: Is it possible my project is too complex and it just cannot parse it?